# number of row with same variable

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (for simpler example)

First table have info about each visitor (redirect)

```
|user_agent||unique_id|
|ua123||321|
|ua231||323|
|ua123||322|
```

Second table is with "sales"

```
|unique_id||price|
|322||1.7|
|321||0.5|
```

I want to know how to build query which will show this:

```
|unique_id||price||number of row with non unique user_agent with sale|
|322||0.7||3|
|321||0.5||1|
```

Comment: Sorry - one mistake:
    |322||0.7||2|
    |321||0.5||1|

Comment: Visits:|NAME||unique_id(of_visit)|  Sales:|unique_id(of_visit)||price|    => |unique_id(of_visit)||price||#ofVisitwithsameNAME|

Comment: If only there was an edit button

Comment: are u sure that given expected output is correct?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select 
    s.unique_id,
    s.price,
    (select count(user_agent) from visitor v where v.unique_id = s.unique_id) as nbr_visit
    from sales s
```

Comment: it's just adding n+1 for each row =(
But I want to know number of visit with user_agent that have sale.

Comment: Visits:|NAME||unique_id(of_visit)|  Sales:|unique_id(of_visit)||price|    => |unique_id(of_visit)||price||#ofVisitwithsameNAME|
So it should say that sale in "322(unique_id_of_visit)"  was #2ofVisitwithsameNAME

Comment: Let me check please=)

Comment: You countering all user_agents with v.unique_id = s.unique_id. But unique_id is unique for each row. And question for my opinion it's more complicated that it' may thinks. Table of visits have visits with and without sales. So let say that one user with ua: "android.4.4(+ip)" will visit us 10 times, but sales will be only in 2nd visit and in 5rd. So i want to add to result column with cell |android.4.4(+ip)||unique_id||price|||2| /// |android.4.4(+ip)||unique_id||price|||5|

Comment: SELECT CON.stream_id,groups.name,CON.status,CON.profit,streams.comments,country,FROM_UNIXTIME(CON.datetime + 7200) AS TIME,FROM_UNIXTIME(detail.time + 7200) AS TIME2, TIMEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(CON.datetime + 7200),FROM_UNIXTIME(detail.time + 7200)) AS lead_after,CON.sub_id
FROM tds_sales AS CON
LEFT JOIN tds_streams AS streams ON streams.id = CON.stream_id
LEFT JOIN tds_stream_groups AS groups ON groups.id = streams.group_id
INNER JOIN tds_stats_20161212 AS detail ON detail.sub_id = CON.sub_id
WHERE (CON.status="install" OR CON.status="" OR CON.status="subscribe")
ORDER BY TIME DESC